# aws_instance - changing volume_size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to increase size of my root volume for my ami `ami-0d013c5896434b38a` - I am using Terraform to provision this.

Just to clarify - I have only one instance. And I want to make sure that if I need to increase the disk space, I don't have to destroy the machine first. Elasticity (EC2)  is my reason to believe that it's doable.

Does anyone know whether this is doable? Yes, I could simply do `terraform plan` and do a dry-run, but just double-checking.

Comment: Have you tried making the change? What does the plan show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ebs_block_device - (Optional) One or more configuration blocks with additional EBS block devices to attach to the instance. Block device configurations only apply on resource creation.

So, as per documentation, **ebs_block_device** can only be applied during creation of the resource. In your case it is an EC2 instance which needs to be re-created.

Comment: OP was actually asking about root_block_device, not ebs_block_device. With recent terraform versions you can resize the root without destroying anything.

Answer (score 23):

I'm running Terraform 1.0.1 and would like to change my `volume_size` from 20gb to 30gb.

After run `terraform apply`

```
[...]
# aws_instance.typo3_staging_1 will be updated in-place
~ resource "aws_instance" "staging_1" {
    id                          = "i-0eb2f8af6c8ac4125"
    tags                        = {
    "Name" = "Staging 1"
    "Team" = "DevOps"
  }
  # (28 unchanged attributes hidden)

  ~ root_block_device {
      tags                  = {}
    ~ volume_size           = 20 -> 30
    # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
  }
  # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
}
Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
[...]
```

I see that terraform will not destroy the system. Now a simple 'yes' change the volume. After ~33sec the root_block_device has been changed.

A login on the ec2 shows nothing has been changed. `df` shows the old 20gb size of the root partition. But a simple `sudo reboot` increased the disk space by 10gb without destoring the current system. All docker containers on that instance runs as expected. Perfect.

My Terraform resource config for such `aws_instance` is:

```
resource "aws_instance" "staging_1" {

  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  ebs_optimized = true

  ami                    = "ami-001183208be54f75c"
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.master_key.key_name
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.web_development_private_a.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ec2_staging.id]

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = 30 # in GB <<----- I increased this!
    volume_type = "gp3"
    encrypted   = true
    kms_key_id  = data.aws_kms_key.customer_master_key.arn
  }

  # This is for T3 only (doesn't apply to M5/R5/...)
  # standard: Baseline of 20% or 30% CPU. Short bursts of 100% CPU are possible, but under a budget. Throttled, if budget is 0.
  # unlimited: Always 100% CPU possible, but costs are higher, if over burst budget.
  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }

  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint = "enabled"
    http_tokens   = "required"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Staging 1"
    Team = "DevOps"
  }
  volume_tags = {
    Name = "Staging 1"
    Team = "DevOps"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is not selected as the correct one. This is the best and easiest answer and saved my ass. Thanks.

Comment: any folks know when does this terraform feature had been added? when we were using terraform 0.14, this method would destroy the who bootdisk and provision a brand new system..cause me a lot of trouble..

Comment: oh wow the use of the root_block_device{} was a real discovery for me, it helped binding the volume directly to the root very efficiently! thanks

Answer (score 5):

It is doable through the [AWS Console or AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/), but not through Terraform, based on a quick test.

Changing the `volume_size` parameter from 10 to 20 in an `aws_instance` definition such as the one below caused a destroy/re-create of the instance. Using Terraform 0.15.0.

If you need to keep managing the instance with Terraform, consider the option of (1) performing the modification outside of Terraform (aws console or CLI) and (2) importing the modified resource back into Terraform.

In the second section of the answer I describe a simple example of re-importing into Terraform the state of the `aws_instance` modified through the console.

**Disclaimer**: do this at your own risk and after suitable testing in a non-production environment. Read carefully the warnings in the documentation for the [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html) command

### Testing EBS modification done in Terraform - requires instance replacement

```
resource "aws_instance" "testebs" {
  availability_zone           = local.aznames[0]
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name                    = "zzzzzzzz"
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_size = 20
  }
}
```

I paste below the full config and the output of `terraform plan`.
The `ami` is a recent Ubuntu 20.04 for `eu-west-1`, not the one in the original question.

File `ebstest.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.15.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "xxxxxxx"
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "root-device-type"
    values = ["ebs"]
  }
  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}
locals {
  aznames = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
}

resource "aws_instance" "testebs" {
  availability_zone           = local.aznames[0]
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name                    = "zzzzzzzz"
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_size = 20
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "testebs-${local.aznames[0]}"
  }
}
```

Output of `terraform plan`:

```
$ terraform plan
aws_instance.testebs: Refreshing state... [id=i-0e1fededb2e432a98]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.testebs must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_instance" "testebs" {
      ~ arn                          = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:instance/i-0e1fededb2e432a98" -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_core_count               = 1 -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_threads_per_core         = 1 -> (known after apply)
      - disable_api_termination      = false -> null
      - ebs_optimized                = false -> null
      - hibernation                  = false -> null
      + host_id                      = (known after apply)
      ~ id                           = "i-0e1fededb2e432a98" -> (known after apply)
      ~ instance_state               = "running" -> (known after apply)
      ~ ipv6_address_count           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ ipv6_addresses               = [] -> (known after apply)
      - monitoring                   = false -> null
      + outpost_arn                  = (known after apply)
      + password_data                = (known after apply)
      + placement_group              = (known after apply)
      ~ primary_network_interface_id = "eni-0a923724fec1e76ce" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_dns                  = "ip-172-31-13-57.eu-west-1.compute.internal" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_ip                   = "172.31.13.57" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_dns                   = "ec2-3-250-102-86.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_ip                    = "3.250.102.86" -> (known after apply)
      ~ secondary_private_ips        = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ security_groups              = [
          - "default",
        ] -> (known after apply)
      ~ subnet_id                    = "subnet-192e767f" -> (known after apply)
        tags                         = {
            "Name" = "testebs-eu-west-1a"
        }
      ~ tenancy                      = "default" -> (known after apply)
      ~ vpc_security_group_ids       = [
          - "sg-d7dc5a9a",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - credit_specification {
          - cpu_credits = "standard" -> null
        }

      + ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = "/dev/sda1"
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 20
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }
      - ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          - delete_on_termination = true -> null
          - device_name           = "/dev/sda1" -> null
          - encrypted             = false -> null
          - iops                  = 100 -> null
          - snapshot_id           = "snap-0f4b18aebb4264157" -> null
          - tags                  = {} -> null
          - throughput            = 0 -> null
          - volume_id             = "vol-01eade74ebeba666f" -> null
          - volume_size           = 10 -> null
          - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
        }

      ~ enclave_options {
          ~ enabled = false -> (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ metadata_options {
          ~ http_endpoint               = "enabled" -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_put_response_hop_limit = 1 -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_tokens                 = "optional" -> (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ root_block_device {
          ~ delete_on_termination = true -> (known after apply)
          ~ device_name           = "/dev/sda1" -> (known after apply)
          ~ encrypted             = false -> (known after apply)
          ~ iops                  = 100 -> (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          ~ tags                  = {} -> (known after apply)
          ~ throughput            = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_id             = "vol-01eade74ebeba666f" -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_size           = 10 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_type           = "gp2" -> (known after apply)
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

### Testing modification through AWS Console and importing resource from terraform (see disclaimer/warning above).

1. Create instance with 10G volume as per the previous part of the answer.
2. [Modify EBS volume](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/) size to 20G in AWS Console.
   (did not extend the volume at OS level -- exercise for the reader :D)
3. List Terraform items in the state file and select `aws_instance` resource for which the *state* will be removed

```
$ terraform state list
data.aws_ami.ubuntu
data.aws_availability_zones.available
aws_instance.testebs
```

3. Remove state ([`terraform state rm`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html)) for the `aws_instance` resource.

```
$ terraform state rm aws_instance.testebs
Removed aws_instance.testebs
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
```

4. Using `terraform import`, import the `aws_resource` using the `instance-id` of the modified EC2 instance.

```
$ terraform import aws_instance.testebs  i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_instance.testebs: Importing from ID "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"...
aws_instance.testebs: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_instance for import
aws_instance.testebs: Refreshing state... [id=i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

4. Verify that terraform can manage the imported instance properly (modify instance through terraform and verify behavior)

Comment: I think my problem is that I already have an EC2 instance running - so if I add `ebs_block_device` it will destroy it - I haven't got much choice here because I need to use Terraform.

Comment: It worked for me when adding root_block_device{} block and setting volume_size appropriately. It also worked on Terraform 0.12.x. One needs to increase the root partition and filesystem size manually afterwards: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html.

Comment: This is old stuff. Recent terraform versions do not destroy the instance anymore.