# Terraform Import aws resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I previously imported ec2 instance in terraform state now I want to bring ec2 root volume under terraform state as well.
On my testing I was able to import ec2 instance and ebs volume using the following commands

```
`terraform import aws_ebs_volume.id vol-01234`
`terraform import aws_instance.myec2 i-12345678`
```

Please help me how I can I import aws_instance.root_block_device ?

Command `terraform import aws_instance.my_ec2.root_block_device vol-01234` does seems to work

Comment: `root_block_device` is  an attribute of the `aws_instance` resource. You don't import attributes, you import resources. The root block device should have been imported as part of the instance resource already.

Comment: Just to complement Mark B's answer, here is a link to an answer detailing the import of an ec2 resource. It shows the root_block_device as part of the state (well, in the plan output).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224607/11915058

Comment: Thanks @MarkB and @RafaP you are correct. I wrote `root_block_device` block in my terraform script and planned it it showed no infrastructure changes and worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to import. I used a method to find "type of reource to import: aws instance, oogle_dns_record_set " from resource in document, input data as required in import